# fatal error C1189: #error : You cannot use 32-bit time_t (_USE_32BIT_TIME_T) with _WIN64

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, 32bit-64bit

I am trying to compile c++ code on 64bit OS. Earlier I used to build 32bit OS for our project. I removed _USE_32BIT_TIME_T processor definition from machine.properties file but still I am getting this error.

If I build in 32 bit OS the compilation runs fine. How can I build 32bit exe on 64bit OS through pipeline scripting ?

I can't change C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(463)

Comment: Are you including `<ctime>` (not `<time.h>`) and are you using `std::time_t` everywhere? If not, it could be worth trying out.

Comment: Then it must be defined somewhere else. Have you definitely done a completely clean build, e.g. delete all PCHs etc.? Can you grep your build tree to find the define? Does VS let you right-click and browse to a #define (I can't remember)? Can you explicitly #undef it before you include windows.h? You say 'pipeline' - is this Jenkins? It's definitely not in your Jenkins configuration?

Comment: Hi Rup, yes this is jenkins. I explicitly set win32_vs10 config in jenkins build configuration but still  it picks up _WIN64. I tried clean build but error persists.

Comment: Hi Ted , yes we are using ctime not time.h and I am using std::time_t .. But I don't understand the difference. Sorry I am at very preliminary stage.